# PHP : Auto sync file when having internet connection

Tags: php, synchronization

Just require a really simple idea as i can't really understand how to achieve the requirement of my project..
my project requirement need to create a simple website with having e-form.
The only problem is that if the user half way entering the information and lost his internet connection, the website should be able to work offline and once the internet connection is back, it should auto sync back the information that entering by the user..
ps. each e-form having few different pages..

Not really sure if it's work same like dropbox but not understand the logic.. 
Appreciate for any help :)

Comment: the website wont work off line if the browser cant access it. i don't see how you think this can work.

Comment: you cannot do this with browser. if you can write a client which can store intermediate data, detect when connection is available, and keep track what has been synced, then you can achieve this, like dropbox.

Comment: @bansi can you explain to me in more details? :( have no experience with this at all...

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can set a timer like this : http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval1

if no connection, ignore the error, if there's connection do your commands....

Comment: never link to 3schools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. seems like i can use javascript to pause the uploading and use this timer to keep on detecting if the user having connection or no .. without connection it will keep show loading.. but the only cons is if the user refresh or close the browser..